# Coroutines: Do co_yielded string_views dangle?

Tags: c++, coroutine, dangling-pointer, c++23

I want to mix up the co_yielding string literals and `std::strings`

```
Generator<std::string_view> range(int first, const int last) {
    while (first < last) {
        char ch = first++;
        co_yield " | ";
        co_yield std::string{ch, ch, ch};
    }
}
```

However, I'm wondering about the lifetime of the std::string?

Maybe it's safe if you know you are going to consume the `string_view` immediately?

```
for(auto sv : range(65, 91))
   std::cout << sv;
```

https://godbolt.org/z/d5eoP9aTE

You could make it safe like this

```
Generator<std::string_view> range(int first, const int last) {
    std::string result;
    while (first < last) {
        char ch = first++;
        co_yield " | ";
        result = std::string{ch, ch, ch};
        co_yield result;
    }
}
```

Comment: If it were stored as a local `std::string` in the coro frame, I’d say it’s fine. I’m guessing this isn’t though. But I don’t know.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`co_yield` is a fancy form of `co_await`. Both of these are expressions. And therefore, they follow the rules of expressions. Temporaries manifested as part of the evaluation of the expression will continue to exist until the completion of the entire expression.

`co_await` expressions do not *complete* until after the coroutine resumes. This is important, as you often `co_await` on prvalues, so if you do something as simple as `co_await some_function()`, you need the return value of `some_function` to continue to exist, as its `await_resume` function needs to be able to be called.

As previously stated, `co_yield` is just a fancy form of `co_await`. So the rules still apply. So any `string_view` objects returned by your generator will point to valid values *between* calls to resume the coroutine.

Comment: *will point to valid values **between calls to resume** the coroutine* - This is extremely important. It means that if one, for example, stores the yielded string_view's into a vector, then all they will get is a "vector of UB" :D